# matplotlib imshow then savefig, twice in a row but with different array, create the same picture, but it should not

Tags: matplotlib

The following code save two images that look exaclty the same, but they should not! (images[0] is definitively different than images[1])

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(images[0])
plt.savefig("image0.png")
#plt.clf()

plt.imshow(images[1])
plt.savefig("image1.png")
```

I tried to use plt.clf but this just make the second image blank

Any idea ?

Comment: `images[0]` and `images[1]` are clearly the same image. The code doesn't show how they are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was another call to plt above and hidden in the code (in a called module), I just put plt.close() there

Answer (score 0):

It is strange, I tried with a minimal reproductible example, and had no issue on saving the images.

May be you can try `plt.gcf()` method (for get current figure) before saving.

An example can be:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_images
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = load_sample_images()     
print(len(dataset.images)) # output 2

plt.imshow(dataset.images[0])
plt.gcf()
plt.savefig("image0.png")

plt.imshow(dataset.images[1])
plt.gcf()
plt.savefig("image1.png")
```

It saves both images correctly.